# Returning a Map value in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, dictionary

I have a data class

```
data class Rates(
    val currency: String,
    val rate: Double
)
```

And to get the value for rate I have done this

```
fun getRate(rates: Map<String, Rates>): Double {
    var rate = 0.0
    val map = rates.values.map {
        it.rate
    }
    map.forEach {
        rate = it
    }

    return rate
}
```

This returns the correct value but I believe there could be a better performant and fewer steps way to do this. How better can I do this?

Comment: `I believe there could be a better way to do this.` better in what way ?

Comment: Your code is no different than returning `rates.values.lastOrNull()?.rate ?: 0.0`. It doesn't seem to me like that's your intended behavior or you wouldn't be doing it in such a complicated way.

Comment: @Tenfour04 never occurred to me I could do it that way. I just know my process could be lots better. Thank you.